# Parsing an XML file in the sdcard - comes up with null pointer exception

Tags: android, xml-parsing, xmlpullparser

All I want is to parse a local XML file. The code works correctly when I place the XML file in my resource folder. Here's my code.

```
try {

        XmlResourceParser xpp = getResources().getXml(R.xml.catalog);
        xpp.next();
        int eventType = xpp.getEventType();
        int iter = 0;
        String elemtext = null;

        while (eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {

            if (eventType == XmlPullParser.START_TAG) {

                String elemName = xpp.getName();
                if (elemName.equals("catalog")) {
                    String journalAttr = xpp.getAttributeValue(null,
                            "journal");
                    String publisherAttr = xpp.getAttributeValue(null,
                            "publisher");
                    journal.setText(journalAttr);
                    publisher.setText(publisherAttr);
                }
                if (elemName.equals("article")) {
                    iter = iter + 1;
                }

                if (elemName.equals("edition")) {
                    elemtext = "edition";
                }
                if (elemName.equals("title")) {
                    elemtext = "title";
                }
                if (elemName.equals("author")) {
                    elemtext = "author";
                }
            }

            else if (eventType == XmlPullParser.TEXT) {
                if (iter == 1) {
                    if (elemtext.equals("edition")) {
                        edition1.setText(xpp.getText());
                    } else if (elemtext.equals("title")) {
                        title1.setText(xpp.getText());
                    } else if (elemtext.equals("author")) {
                        author1.setText(xpp.getText());
                    }
                }

                else if (iter == 2) {
                    if (elemtext.equals("edition")) {
                        edition2.setText(xpp.getText());
                    } else if (elemtext.equals("title")) {
                        title2.setText(xpp.getText());
                    } else if (elemtext.equals("author")) {
                        author2.setText(xpp.getText());
                    }

                }
            }
            eventType = xpp.next();
        }

    } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
    } catch (IOException e) {
    }
```

now my intention is to get the code working if the same file is placed in the sdcard.
here's my efforts.

```
try {

        XmlPullParserFactory factory = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
        factory.setNamespaceAware(true);
        XmlPullParser xpp = factory.newPullParser();
        int eventType = xpp.getEventType();
        int iter = 0;
        String elemtext = null;
        // get a reference to the file.
        File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                + "/newdir/catalog.xml");
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);

        xpp.setInput(new InputStreamReader(fis));

        while (eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {

            if (eventType == XmlPullParser.START_TAG) {

                String elemName = xpp.getName();
                if (elemName.equals("catalog")) {
                    String journalAttr = xpp.getAttributeValue(null,
                            "journal");
                    String publisherAttr = xpp.getAttributeValue(null,
                            "publisher");
                    journal.setText(journalAttr);
                    publisher.setText(publisherAttr);
                }
                if (elemName.equals("article")) {
                    iter = iter + 1;
                }

                if (elemName.equals("edition")) {
                    elemtext = "edition";
                }
                if (elemName.equals("title")) {
                    elemtext = "title";
                }
                if (elemName.equals("author")) {
                    elemtext = "author";
                }
            }

            else if (eventType == XmlPullParser.TEXT) {
                if (iter == 1) {
                    if (elemtext.equals("edition")) {
                        edition1.setText(xpp.getText());
                    } else if (elemtext.equals("title")) {
                        title1.setText(xpp.getText());
                    } else if (elemtext.equals("author")) {
                        author1.setText(xpp.getText());
                    }
                }

                else if (iter == 2) {
                    if (elemtext.equals("edition")) {
                        edition2.setText(xpp.getText());
                    } else if (elemtext.equals("title")) {
                        title2.setText(xpp.getText());
                    } else if (elemtext.equals("author")) {
                        author2.setText(xpp.getText());
                    }

                }
            }
            eventType = xpp.next();
        }

    } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
    } catch (IOException e) {
    }
```

I get null pointer exception when i use this code. Help me sort this out.

Comment: Do you want to check file's name, if there are two file with same name? yes?

Comment: I have a file with exactly the same name in the sdcard. (The path and name is correct)

Comment: What line in your pasted code throws the NullPointerException?

Comment: if (iter == 1) {
                    if (elemtext.equals("edition")) {
                        edition1.setText(xpp.getText());  this line throws exception

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This example is same with your need](http://qtcstation.com/2011/01/parsing-xml-from-the-sdcard-using-xmlpullparser/)

Comment: This link takes me nowhere. Please check the link.

Comment: @Sean_22 Try and add more details to your answer; this will be helpful even if provided link stops working in future.

Answer (score 1):

I think you didn't address correctly. check my suggestion:

```
File root = android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
String a = root.getAbsolutePath() + "/newdir/catalog.xml";
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(a);
```

Comment: I tried this in my code. I got rid of the null pointer exception. but the XML is not getting parsed

Comment: @StephenSherbatsky: Do you check xpp object? If it was empty, you should check your address.